# Facebook API Permission Denied when accessing /{user_id}/live_videos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, live-streaming

My app has approved the scope: `publish_video`, `publish_pages`, `manage_pagesive`.

My status app is live and version 3,3.

When I request accessing `/{user_id}/live_videos` for get rtmp link then I get the exception below:

> (#10) To use live-video-api on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

I have tested on status development, when I request  `/{user_id}/live_videos`, Facebook API return rtmp link.

Please explain to me!

Comment: Have you read the link that the error provided you with? It mentions that in order to get your app approved, because it is using the `live-video API`, it has to be **reviewed and approved by Facebook**. Did you just recently added the scope for live-video?

Comment: _“Please explain to me!”_ - the exception message you got already did that …

Comment: Hi @Chax, when I login facebook with scope "publish_video, publish_pages, manage_pagesive". I had check access token permisions, it had the permissions ( "publish_video, publish_pages, manage_pagesive"). I had live video successul while app status  is development, but I switch status to "live", it throw that exception.

Comment: @datntdatnt Right on the page provided in the error message there is this **info box** that says __If you switch your app to Live mode before you have been approved, you will lose access to all data including that of your app, test users, test pages, and app developers and app admins.__

Have you read the information in [that page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)?

Comment: @Chax My app had approved.

This is the list permisions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vrt5.png
I had business verification
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGuBu.png

Answer (score 0):

@Chax
My app had approved.

This is the list permisions:
[permisions evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vrt5.png)

I had business verification

[business verification evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGuBu.png)